# Create charts in excel with only last 10 values

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

Thanks in Advance

My question is below:

I have 8 Columns in my sheet as below

Date | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I

I want to plot 2 graphs for 10 latest entries

1st Graph contains Date, A, C, and H
and 2nd Graph contains Date, D, E, and I

What I was able to do is create a Defined Name for each column and add it but I feel this is a lengthy task.

To create Defined Name for each column I used `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$2,COUNT(Sheet1!$D:$D),0,-10,1)`
using which I am able to get the last 10 entries

What I want to achieve is, Instead of creating a Defined Name for each column is there any other way we can directly get the last 10 entries for all the columns for which I want to plot?

Comment: You could "copy" them to a different location and use that table. But I assume that is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I don't want that, even I can't change the column sequence